# Dereferencing null pointer warning and code run stuck infinitely

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, nullpointerexception, null-pointer

So i am trying to solve a problem to reverse a linked list and following is what i came up with.

```
class Solution
{
public:

   /* void insertList(struct Node* head, int data)
    {
        Node* temp{ head };
        while (temp->next != nullptr)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        Node* nextNode{ new Node(data) };
        temp->next = nextNode;
    }*/
    void insertPrev(struct Node* revHead, int data)
    {
        Node* temp{ new Node(data) };
        temp->next = revHead;
        revHead = temp;
    }
    //Function to reverse a linked list.
    struct Node* reverseList(struct Node* head)
    {
        if (head == NULL)
            return head;
        Node* revHead{ new Node(head->data) };
        Node* temp{ head->next };
        while (temp != NULL);//this line
        {
            insertPrev(revHead, temp->data);//this line 2
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        return revHead;
    }
};
```

when i am trying to run this code to reverse a linked list. it gets stuck infinitely on this line which i have commented as this line. Moreover, ide throws warning also that i may be potentially derefercing a null pointer in this line 2. I don't know how is that possible when i just checked above that temp should not be null for the while loop to run. Help please!

Comment: help please someone

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: To reverse a linked list (like `std::list`), just use [std::reverse](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) - one line of code and problem solved.

Comment: You should always post code as a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that people can cut'n'paste, compile and run. The shown code fails in this regard (for example; there's no `main` function).

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  The `while(temp!= NULL)` is immediately followed by a `;`.   So, if `temp` is not equal to `NULL`, that is an infinite loop - and the `{` on the next line is never reached.   That would also explain the warning.  If the `insertPrev()` call is reached, `temp` is `NULL` and evaluating `temp->data` (and `temp->next` on the next line) gives undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues in your code:

- `while (temp != NULL);//this line` represents an infinite loop. The semicolon represents an empty body for this `while` construct. Remove it.
- `insertPrev` modifies a local variable `revHead`: the caller's variable with the same name will not be modified by it. To fix this, define the parameter as pass-by-reference: `void insertPrev(struct Node* &revHead, int data)` (add the `&`).

This will fix the issue.

### Other remarks

As this is C++ code:

- Don't declare variables with `struct Node*`, but just `Node*`.
- Don't use a mix of `NULL` and `nullptr`: only use `nullptr`

Depending on what was asked in the challenge, you could solve this by reversing the linked list in place, without needing to create new nodes.